# Form Validation in jquery

Tags: jquery, validation

I need to validate one regular expression. Format is like this `ITBG/SER/AMC-PA` or `ITBG/SER/AMC-RN` or `ITBG/SER/AMC-OT`. ie last field contains either `pa` or `rn` or `ot`. Please help

Comment: `var regex = /^ITBG\/SER\/AMC\-(pa|rn|ot)$/i`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var regex = /^ITBG\/SER\/AMC\-(pa|rn|ot)$/i
```